# Android intent-filter for http scheme

Tags: android, android-manifest

I built an Android application that requires OAuth. All was working well using a custom scheme call back which is intercepted by Android.  It seems that Yahoo have changed the goal posts and now the custom scheme is not accepted by Yahoo.

I am now looking at possible alternate approaches.  My first attempt is to use a normal http scheme and modify my intent filter to intercept the new URL.  I have the following in my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:host="www.test.com" android:scheme="http"></data> 
  </intent-filter>
```

Where www.test.com will be substituted with a domain that I own. It seems :

- This filter is triggered when I click on a link on a page.
- It is not triggered on the redirect by Yahoo, the browser opens the website at www.test.com
- It is not triggered when I enter the domain name directly in the browser.

So can anybody help me with

- When exactly this intent-filter will be triggered?
- Any changes to the intent-filter or permissions that will widen the filter to apply to redirect requests?
- Any other approaches I could use?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: oh no i currently have the exact same problem, so i really have to create a redirection script? there must be a better solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an alternative solution, placing on your www.test.com a script that extracts the oauth parameters and redirects to your custom scheme callback?

Such as for instance oauth.php (pardon my PHP ...)

```
<?
header('Location:myschema://mythost?oauth_verifier='.urlencode( $_GET['oauth_verifier']).
    '&oauth_token='.urlencode($_GET['oauth_token']));
die();
?>
```

I am succesfully using it for Google OAuth which has the same restriction on the callback URL.

Comment: Thanks.  That is the approach I also used in the end.  It is clunky but it works.  Just frustrating to add an additional hop in to the process.